# C# Generic Type Parameter with a Conditional Statement

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm working with an API in C# with some classes as follows. There are two message classes `MessageA` and `MessageB` and a number of field classes `FieldA`, `FieldB`, etc. The field classes all belong to a base class `Field`.

A message will contain various fields which can be accessed as

`msgA.getField(FieldX field)`

(copies the `FieldX` entry (if it exists) from `msgA` to `field`) and

`msgB.set(FieldX field)`.

There's also

`msgA.isSetField(FieldX field)`

to make sure a message contains a field of type `FieldX`.

I need to write a method to take a `MessageA` and copy over some of fields to a `MessageB`. I have a working function now, but it has a whole bunch of statements like

```
FieldX fieldX = new FieldX();
if(msgA.isSetField(fieldX))
{
    msgA.getField(fieldX);
    msgB.set(fieldX);
}
```

This seems silly to me, so I'd like to write a separate method to do this. I'm new to C# and generic types though, so I'm not quite sure the best way to do it. After trying a number of things, I've written

```
private void SetMessageB<T>(MessageA msgA, MessageB msgB, Field field) where T : Field
{
    var field_t = field as T;
    if (field_t != null)
    {
        if (msgA.isSetField(field_t))
        {
            msgA.getField(field_t);
            msgB.set(field_t);
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. Within the inner conditional statement, the type of `field_t` gets converted to `int`. It sort of makes sense *why* this would happen (i.e., these functions can't take any type as an argument, so the compiler can't be sure it will work every time). But I'm wondering if someone can point out a good way to solve the problem. Feel free to link me to MSDN articles or tutorials or whatnot. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried using `T field` in your method signature instead of `Field field`? Reduces the need for a cast.

Comment: Good point, it does simplify it, but the problem persists. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would only make sense to use generics here if your message object's methods were generic as well:

```
class Message
{
   bool isSetField<TField>(TField field) where TField  : Field { ... }
   void getField<TField>(TField field) where TField  : Field { ... }
   void set<TField>(TField field) where TField  : Field { ... }
}
```

Then your method can be truly generic:

```
private void SetMessageB<T>(Message msgA, Message msgB, T field) where T : Field
{
    if (msgA.isSetField(field))
    {
      msgA.getField(field);
      msgB.set(field);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. Do you have any ideas on how I might accomplish this? I also thought about making a List<Field>, adding a bunch of new `FieldX`'s to it, but I had a similar problem.

Comment: You'll have to provide more details on what you would like to accomplish exactly. With a list of mixed field types, you would still have to resort to casting.

Comment: I'd just like to clean up my method a bit. Right now I have about 20 of these statements, so I'd imagine there must be some way to make it less repetitive. But everytime I try something (e.g., passing to a different method or using a list of mixed types), I run into trouble because the fields are all different types. I'm assuming there's a construction that would allow me to only write this setup once, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: You might want to look at using delegates like `Func<TField,TValue>` and pass them as lambdas (e.g.,`field => field.Value`) to a method that accepts generic `Field` objects but then calls the delegate to get the type-specific value from the field. If you can only find out the type at run-time (e.g., like with a mixed list), you would have to use Reflection or `dynamic` instead.